# defining rounding tolerance in functools.lru_cache decorator

Tags: python

I am decorating a function using the `functools.lru_cache` decorator to avoid repeated executions when the inputs do not change.

The arguments of the function I'm decorating, however, are `float`s. In addition to this, I know that the output of the function is not too sensitive to small changes in the inputs so that, for the sake of execution speed, I'd like to sacrifice a little bit of precision if this can reduce the number of execution. I would therefore add a *tollerance* to my `lru_cache`.

Consider the following example:

```
import functools

@functools.lru_cache
def square(x):
    print(f'calling square with input {str(x)}')
    return x**2

out = [square(v) for v in [1, 5/5, 1.000000001, 2.0002]]
```

This produces the following output:

```
>> calling square with input 1
>> calling square with input 1.0
>> calling square with input 1.000000001
>> calling square with input 2.0002
```

There are a number of problems with this:

1. `1` and `5/5` (i.e. `float(1)`) are not captured to be the same input, even if `typed=False` (by default) in the `lru_cache` call.
2. `1.0` and `1.000000001` are not captured to be the same input

The only solution I could think of is to design a wrapper to do this for me.
A very "dirty" implementation could be something like this:

```
def round_input(tol):
    def decorator(fun):
        @wraps(fun)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            args = [arg//tol*tol for arg in args]
            kwargs = {k: v//tol*tol for k,v in kwargs.items()}
            return fun(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper
    return decorator

@round_input(1)
@lru_cache
def square(x):
    print(f'calling square with input {str(x)}')
    return x**2


out = [square(v) for v in [1, float(1), 1.000000001, 2.0002]]

>> calling square with input 1
>> calling square with input 1.0
>> calling square with input 2.0
```

This solves problem number 2, but it adds a new small problem: `2.0002` is rounded even if this rounding does not produce any match with subsequent calls. An ideal approach could be to check if we already called this function with an input within `tol` so that we can take benefit of the cache and **only then** accept the rounding.

Is there a neat and clean way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to store a list of past calls in the wrapper and check against them before actually performing the rounding.

For example

```
def round_input(tol):
    past = {}
    def round_fun(x):
        if (val:= round(x/tol)*tol) in past:
            return past[val]
        else:
            past[val] = x
            return x

    def decorator(fun):
        @functools.wraps(fun)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            args = [round_fun(arg) for arg in args]
            kwargs = {k: round_fun(v) for k,v in kwargs.items()}
            return fun(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Using this we'd obtaind

```
@round_input(0.1)
@functools.lru_cache
def square(x):
    print(f'calling square with input {str(x)}')
    return x**2


out = [square(v) for v in [1, float(1), 1.000000001, 2.0002, 2]]
>> calling square with input 1
>> calling square with input 2.0002
```

This achieve two goals:

1. `1` and `float(1)` are now executed only once (the reason for this is still a bit obscure to me)
2. `2.0002` is met first and it's executed as it is. Only in the following call the input `2` is within the tolerance. Only then the cache is called and the execution is skipped (accepting a small error since `2**2 != 2.0002**2`)